How does the linker control the visibility of main() defined in a static library?
If I define a main() function in a static library libmy.a (like flex libl.a does),
$ nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libl.a

libmain.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U exit
0000000000000000 T main
                 U yylex

...

#include <stdio.h>
  
int main() {
    printf("Current file: %s\n", __FILE__);
    printf("Current line: %d\n", __LINE__);
    return 0;
}

// $ gcc -c libmy.c -o libmy.o
// $ ar rcs libmy.a libmy.o
// $ nm libmy.a 
// 
// libmy.o:
//                  U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
// 0000000000000000 T main
//                  U printf


I can even make a program from a blank C source file with this static library.
$ # make an empty C source file
$ touch main.c
$ gcc main.c -L. -lmy
$ ./a.out 
Current file: libmy.c
Current line: 5

But if I explicitly define the main() function, the main() function in the static library libmy.a seems to be invisible, otherwise gcc will report an error "redefinition of ‘main’". How is this done?
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
}

// $ gcc main.c -L. -lmy
// $ ./a.out 
Hello World


There seems to be no magic if(like if __name__ == "__main__" in Python) in the static library, at least I do not need to explicitly write this.

The static-libraries tag wiki will help.

The linker only collects undefined symbols from the library.  If main is already defined when the library is scanned, the linker ignores the main in the library.  So, it's not a question of it being invisible; it is a question of "it is ignored".
Problems arise when an object file in the library defines both main and some other symbol that the program uses (that is not defined before the library is linked).  Suppose the object file in the library contains both main and dummy, and your code calls dummy but does not define it (but does define main).  Then you will get a 'multiply defined' error for main.
